# Question on existence of square root function!

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I have a **relation** $f$ defined as

$$
f=\{(x, y) \mid y=\sqrt{x} \;\text { and }\; y, x \in \Bbb R\}
$$

Now this relation is a **function**.  But how? A function is a relation whose every element in domain have only one image in codomain. Now if I have $4$. Then 
\begin{align}
\sqrt{4}=\pm 2
\end{align}

So I have two ordered pairs whose second element is square root of first element: 
\begin{align}
(4,2) \quad \text { and } \quad(4,-2)
\end{align}

Now you can observe that 4 has two images. Therefore relation $f$ must not be a function. But it is! How this is possible?

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof  but the function in this question is defined as $f(x)=√x$ . So if we don't follow the positive sign convention of square root then the argument of question is legit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By convention, $\sqrt{x}$ means the positive square root of $x$. So $\sqrt{4}=2$.

Also note that in order for $f$ to have codomain $\mathbb{R}$, you need to restrict the domain of $f$ to the non-negative reals.

Comment: But how do I know when to use only positive value of √x or not. In solving quadratic equation one must consider both possiblity of answers but here we are considering only principle answer.

Comment: @Orientalem When solving for example $z^2=4$, we have $z=\pm\sqrt{4}=\pm 2$. We have roots $\sqrt{4}=2$ and $-\sqrt{4}=-2$. By itself, $\sqrt{4}$ is just $2$.

Comment: Ohh! Thanks mvpq. So if I define a relation $f$: \begin{align}
f= \ (x, y) | y=\pm \sqrt{x} \text { and } y, x \in R\}
\end{align} then this relation $f$ isn't a function 'cause of more then one image.

Comment: Yes, that's right

Answer (score 0):

With the usual positivity convention there is a difference between

$$R_1 = \{(x,y) \mid x= y^2 \}$$ and

$$R_2 = \{(x,y) \mid \sqrt{x}= y \}$$

$(4,-2),(4,2) \in R_1$ but of these two only $(4,2) \in R_2$.

$R_1$ is not a function and $R_2$ is.